# Como cambiar el formato de un número en una tabla HTML

Tags: javascript, html, thymeleaf

Estoy intentando coambiar el formato de este número en HTML. Tengo una aplicación donde tengo que formatear el número como si fuera hora. Tengo el siguiente fragmento de código:

```
<td th:text="${campaign.starthour}"></td>
```

Esta es el valor de una mis columnas de una tabla, actualmente el número se muestra así en la tabla
"1050", pero necesito que se muestre así "10:50".

Comment: Puedes hacer una funcion que le pases ese valor y te lo devuelva formateado.<td th:text="${nuevoFormato(campaign.starthour)}"></td>, o claro, puedes ver desde donde viene ese valor campaign y formatearlo directamente, antes de usarlo, ¿sabes de donde viene?

Comment: Si se de donde viene, pero necesito formatearlo en el front y no en el back.

Comment: Excelente, entiendo, pero el front lo recibe en algun lado, es ahi donde tienes que modificarlo, ¿puedes agregar la parte del front que presenta esos datos?

Comment: Si es ahi donde tengo que modificarlo, esa es una etiqueta de mi tabla, unico lugar que muestra ese dato.

Comment: Entiendo Brandon, pero ese dato, el front tiene que estar obteniendolo de alguna forma y esa forma es donde lo tienes que modificar, de otra manera, puedes utilizar la forma que te propuse, generar una funcion que haga la modificacion directamente.

Comment: Si, necesito modificarlo como lo propusiste, si no que no se como xd.

Answer (score 0):

Aca te dejo algunos ejemplos, se puede hacer de muchas formas, tu eliges.

```js
let hora = 1050;


const formatHour = (hour) => { 
  const [h,h1,m,m1] = hour.toString().split('');
  return h + h1 + ':' + m + m1;
}
console.log('destructuring', formatHour(hora))


const formatHour1 = (hour) => { 
  let h = hour.toString().split('');
  h.splice(2,0,':')
  return h.join('')
}
console.log('arrays', formatHour1(hora))


const formatHour2 = (hour) => hour.substring(0,2) + ":" + hour.substring(2,4)
console.log('subString', formatHour2(hora.toString()))


const formatHour3 = (hour) => hour.replace(/.{2}/, '$&:');
console.log('regEx ',formatHour3(hora.toString()))
```